# creating raining animation with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on creating rainy animation.

Here's what i have tried.
I created a rain drop view using `CSS` and tried to create multiple rain views using `JavaScript` modifying its position with `padding-right`. But on my webpage I can only see only one rain is dropping.

Can anyone help me to find out what did i wrong?

html:

```
<main></main>
<script src="rain.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.drop {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    width: 7px;
    height: 50px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: drop 0.7s linear infinite;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const main = document.querySelector('main');

let htmlString = '<div class="drop"></div>';

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    htmlString += '<div class="drop" style="padding-right:{i}px></div>';
}

main.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a template string

```
htmlString += `<div class="drop" style="padding-right:${i}px></div>`
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, still showing only one rain drop not multiple ones

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the option of using template string syntax, then you can use regular string concatenation.

```js
htmlString += '<div class="drop" style="padding-right:'+i+'px"></div>';
```

Comment: That is the exact same answer than the one already given (and about which the OP said it is not working). Only you haven't used backticks notation